# What is actually happening on uploading the files from FileZilla ? Are we hosting it ? , if yes how it is actually linked with web hosting provider?

Tags: ftp, web, filezilla, hosting, web-hosting

I just want to know what is happening while uploading the files from FileZilla. From FileZilla can we host a website ? In internet its is saying that, FileZilla is used for uploading downloading files from internet.

Need some clarification

Comment: Possible duplicate https://superuser.com/questions/835805/different-definitions-of-upload-and-download

Comment: FileZilla is a FTP client mostly (apparently in Windows it can also create a basic FTP server but not HTTP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection to FileZilla FTP server works, but directory listing fails](https://superuser.com/questions/729876/connection-to-filezilla-ftp-server-works-but-directory-listing-fails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileZilla is an FTP (File Transfer Protocol) program used to connect to and transfer files to and from an FTP server. FileZilla itself does not host any websites.

However, many servers running apache or nginx (or any other webserver software) will also run an FTP server that's configured so that items uploaded to that server will be visible on the websites hosted on that server.